# How to output a directory meta hash value when the user selects that choice?

Tags: java, hash

Beginner here, I need my program to output hash values for 3 things:

- Files
- Directories
- Directory Meta

I have got the files and directories working but i just can't figure out how to do the directory meta hash values. So far when the user enters the directory and chooses choice '2' the directory meta is shown but with no hash value. So all that i need is to have the program output the hash value for directory meta alongside all the other outputs. My code is shown below: (Thanks in advance to anyone who helps)

**Main Class**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Scanner Scanscan = new Scanner(System.in);
    HashFunction hf = new HashFunction();
    System.out.println("Input File or Directory Path:");

    while(true) {
    String filename = Scanscan.nextLine();
    File inputFile = new File(filename);
    long hash = 0;
    if(filename.equals("exit")){


    if (inputFile.isFile()) {
        hash = hf.produceFileHash(inputFile.getAbsolutePath());

        System.out.println(String.format("The File Hash Value is: %016X", hash));   

    } else if (inputFile.isDirectory()) {
        System.out.println("Please choose either '1' - Directory Hash OR '2' - Directory Meta");
        String Choice = Scanscan.nextLine();
        if (Choice.equals("1")) {
            hash = hf.produceDirHash(inputFile.getAbsolutePath());
            System.out.println(String.format("The Directory Hash Value is: %016X", hash));
            //System.exit(0);

        } else if (Choice.equals("2")) {
            hash = hf.produceDirMetaHash(inputFile.getAbsolutePath());



        }

        }

    }

}

}
}
```

**HashChecker Class**

```
public interface HashChecker {

long produceFileHash(String filename);

long produceDirHash(String path);

long produceDirMetaHash(String path);
}
```

**HashFunction Class**

```
@Override
public long produceDirMetaHash(String path) {
    int FileCount = 0;
    File dirmeta = new File(path);
    File[] listOfFiles = dirmeta.listFiles();

    for (File listOfFile : listOfFiles) {
        Path file = listOfFile.toPath();
        BasicFileAttributes attr = null;
        try {
            attr = Files.readAttributes(file, BasicFileAttributes.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (listOfFile.isFile()) {
            FileCount++;
            System.out.println("\nFile Number: " + FileCount);
            System.out.println("File Name: " + listOfFile.getName());
            System.out.println("Path: " + listOfFile.getPath());
            System.out.println("Created: " + attr.creationTime());
            System.out.println("Last Accessed: " + attr.lastAccessTime());
            System.out.println("Last Modified: " + attr.lastModifiedTime());
            System.out.println("Regular File: " + attr.isRegularFile());
            System.out.println("Size: " + attr.size());

            System.out.println("File Name " + listOfFile.getName());
            System.out.println("Path " + listOfFile.getPath());
            FileCount++;
            System.out.println("File Number " + FileCount);
        }
    }
    return FileCount;
}
}
```

[Example of the hash output i need but instead for directory meta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0d0Bk.png)

Comment: Can you give some examples of which outputs you are expecting, all I see is that your `produceDirMetaHash` is only doing a simple count of the files inside the directory passed, If that is what you want then maybe the directory you pass to is simply does not contain any regular files.

Comment: hi here is the example, https://i.stack.imgur.com/0d0Bk.png i basically need that sort of hash value but for when i choose option 2 which is the directory meta

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach:

1. Create a [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html).
2. Encapsulate the `ByteArrayOutputStream` in an [`ObjectOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html).
3. Write all the attributes in the `ObjectOutputStream`.
4. Use the method [`toByteArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#toByteArray--) to convert all the attributes into bytes.
5. Do whatever hash you need to with those bytes... For example you can use [`Arrays#hashCode(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#hashCode-byte:A-) for the simplest solution, or use [`MessageDigest`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) for a better solution.

For the `FileTime` types use `toInstant()` method to convert them to `Serializable`.